# react-native: How to setState() dynamic state in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can create dynamic state like this example:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
}
```

create state with this method:

```
func(name){
   this.state[name];
}
```

and setState with this:

```
func2(name,value){
   this.setState({[name]:value});
}
```

so with

```
this.func('color');
this.func('size');
```

I have `this.func.color` and `this.func.size`. right?

It works.

But I want something like this. I want create all new dynamic state in `'names'` state.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {names:[]};
}
```

`names` is a normal state.

```
func(name){
       this.state.names[name];
}

func2(name,value){
   this.setState({names:{[name]:value}:});
}
```

I call this functions:

```
func('color');
func('size');

func2('color','red');
func2('size','larg');
```

I expect  with `console.log(this.state.names)` this:

```
{color:'red',size:'larg'}
```

But I get only `{size:'larg'}`  (second function)

what is my wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting the value of `names` when you call `this.setState` again.

You're effectively doing:

```
this.setState({ names: { color: 'red' }});
this.setState({ names: { size: 'large' }});
```

Consider using `Object.assign()` in `func2` to make sure you're not replacing the object you're trying to add properties to.

```
func2(name,value) {
    this.setState({
        names: Object.assign(this.state.names, {[name]: value})
    });
}
```